# Change value of multidimensional php array with function result

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the feeling I am missing something simple. I need to change the value of a key in a multi dimensional array based on the result of a function. Here is my array $exports

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array (
    [captain] => Yes 
    [uniform] => 3 
    [fname] => Sally 
    [lname] => Smith
    [position1] => OH
    [position2] => 
    [position3] => 
    [bio] =>
    [classyear] => 2015
    [hft] => 5
    [hin] => 7
)
[1] => Array (
    [captain] => Yes
    [uniform] => 2 
    [fname] => Danielle
    [lname] => Smith
    [position1] => L 
    [position2] => S
    [position3] => OH
    [bio] =>
    [classyear] => 2016
    [hft] => 5
    [hin] => 2
)
[2] => Array (
    [captain] => No
    [uniform] => 4
    [fname] => Erica
    [lname] => Smith
    [position1] => RS
    [position2] =>
    [position3] =>
    [bio] => 
    [classyear] => 2018
    [hft] => 5
    [hin] => 9
)
)
```

This is the code I am using.

```
foreach($exports as $key => &$value) 
    { 
        foreach($value as $key1 => &$value1) 
        { 
            if( $key1 == "classyear") $value1=JHtml::_('helper.gradenumber', $value1, $season);
        } 
    unset($value1); 
    } 
    unset($value);  

    return $exports;
```

This is within Joomla so the JHml line is my function. If I replace this with a string, then my array is updated correctly, but using the function, my classyear key is empty. I have tested and know the function is returning the correct value.

Comment: What is your expected result in `$exports` ??

Comment: I am expecting the result of my function to replace the existing value of the classyear key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like what you have should mostly work, but in this part:

```
$value1=JHtml::_('helper.gradenumber', $value1['classyear'], $season)
```

I think `$value1['classyear']` should just be `$value1`,

because `if( $key1 == "classyear")` then `$value1` will just be a number.

Also, if you are seeing all the results of the classyear function first, you may have it echoing the value instead of returning it.

You could probably use `array_walk` for this.

```
array_walk($exports, function (&$value) use ($season) {
    $value['classyear'] = JHtml::_(
       'helper.gradenumber', $value['classyear'], $season);
});
```

Comment: Like I said, I knew I was missing something simple. You are correct, the gradenumber function was echoing the value, not returning it. It's tucked away in a helper file and I never verified. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You referenced to your `$value` and `$value1`, and then `unset` them. Do not use references, instead of that, update the value like this:

```
foreach ($exports as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1) {
        if ($key1 == "classyear") {
            $exports[$key1] = JHtml::_('helper.gradenumber', $export['classyear'], $season);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That was my first effort. The result of this in the final array is that classyear is empty and the number is printed  before the array. For example if the results of the classyear function are 12, 10, 9, if I do a print_r on the $exports array I get 12,10,9 the array ( 0, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Can use `array_key_exists()` to check key exist or not. No need to use nested `foreach()` . Example:

```
$finalArray = array();
foreach($exports as $key => $value)
{
    if(array_key_exists("classyear", $value)){
        $value["classyear"] = JHtml::_('helper.gradenumber', $export['classyear'], $season);
    }
    $finalArray[] = $value;
}
```

Comment: I get the same results as if using @lolka_bolka suggestion. The function result printed before the array.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this code, but `array_walk_recursive()` seems to me to be the way to handle this:

```
function changeKey(&$item, $key) {
    if($key == 'classyear') {
        $classYear = $item;
        $item = JHtml::_('helper.gradenumber', $classYear, $season);
    }
}

array_walk_recursive($exports, 'changeKey');
```

Comment: same result, the value of item gets put before array. So 12109 array ( 0 etc. The classyear key is empty. If I set $item = to a number, then that number gets put into the exports array correctly. I've echo'd $item within the function to verify that the function gradenumber is returning the correct value.